# Import text file into mySQL don't know table datatypes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to import a textfile into MySQL in the terminal. The text file is too large to open and take a look at, but I know that it's bar '|' delimited.

I found a blog that said do this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.txt'
INTO TABLE db1.table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

I tried that but SQL told me to create the table first, which I did. But it wants to know the field names too I believe. Research online seems to suggest that when I make the table I must specify the field headings and their data type.

Is there a way around this? There are about 20 field names I'd have to type in and I don;t even know their data types.

Is there another way?

**Edit following comments**

I managed to get the head using head -n 3 path/to/file and the results are:

```
   
NIM_EVENT_ID|NIM_EVENT_DATA_TYPE_ID|NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID|EVENT_TIMESTAMP|EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP|PRODUCT_ISSUE_ID|NIM_TITLE_ID|NIM_ISSUE_ID|NIM_USER_ID|RECORD_ID|TRANSACTION_ID|DWELL_MINUTES|FREE_TRIAL_FLAG|UNLIMITED_FLAG|APPLICATION_VERSION_ID|DEVICE_GUID|DEVICE_INFO_ID|DEVICE_BRAND|DEVICE_PRODUCT|DEVICE_TYPE|DEVICE_HARDWARE|DEVICE_MANUFACTURER|DEVICE_MODEL|DEVICE_OS|DEVICE_OS_VERSION|DEVICE_DISPLAY_INFO|DEVICE_DISPLAY_SIZE|DEVICE_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION_ID|EVENT_VERSION|SOURCE_CREATE_TIMESTAMP|SOURCE_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP|WORKFLOW_RUN_ID|ETL_CREATE_DATE|ETL_UPDATE_DATE|SOURCE_FILE_ID
    103008184|879|883|2013-12-07 00:30:35.027000|2013-12-07 05:30:35.027000|-1|4800010|36000003|57700008|61906389|21385144|0|Y|Y||4c22c4a3-094a-476f-9a48-c67b15c2d3f7|-2|||||||||||887|2|2013-12-06 21:35:39.023000|2013-12-06 21:35:39.023000||2013-12-07 03:31:33.910000|2013-12-07 03:31:33.910000|
    98500241|875|880|2013-12-07 15:43:36.984000|2013-12-07 20:43:36.984000|-1|-2|-2|82700012|63226292|||N|N|-i6.1.3-APPLE-3.10.0|45F4BCE1-A6DC-4A66-A071-7D628FC7522E|21|Apple|iPhone OS|iPad|iPad|Apple|iPad|iOS|6.1.3|iPad|DisplayMetrics{width=768.000000, height=1024.000000, scale=2.000000}|887|2|2013-12-07 12:45:50.099000|2013-12-07 12:45:50.099000||2013-12-07 19:31:34.470000|2013-12-07 19:31:34.470000|
```

I'm guessing that what folk my tell me here is to make a script to copy in the head and field info in order to create the .SQL table? Is that what we're doing - copying the formats from the head in order to make a table to import the txt file to?

Comment: Quick FYI - That would more commonly be called being pipe delimited

Comment: Is it a database dump or a table dump? Can you read/view the tail or head of the file?

Comment: @crnlx I have about 10 tables I must load in as a database. I was going to do each one individually into a table. Are you saying there's a way to import a group of text files as a database where each text file is a table?

Comment: Where did you get those from? How were they created? Do they have the table description at the beginning?

Comment: @crnlx From some guy in another dept who knows nothing more. I don't know how they were created. There are no descriptions (I can see "preview file" in Mac)

Comment: This comment box is too short, I will try to create an answer.

Comment: Alright, done. I hope that is clear enough.

Comment: To get first 3 lines of your file, without loading the whole file into an editor, do this in terminal `head -n 3 /tmp/data.txt`. Then copy and post them in your question.

Comment: @peterm done - Do I have to manually look at the output and try to determine each field int he new SQL table? Is there a shortcut using this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Do I have to manually look at the output and try to determine each field int he new SQL table? Is there a shortcut using this output?*

A good text editor is your best friend. Here is what I came up with in a couple of minutes with TextMate

```sql
CREATE TABLE import_table 
(
  nim_event_id INT,
  nim_event_data_type_id INT,
  nim_event_type_id INT,
  event_timestamp DATETIME,
  event_gmt_timestamp DATETIME,
  product_issue_id INT,
  nim_title_id INT,
  nim_issue_id INT,
  nim_user_id INT,
  record_id INT,
  transaction_id INT,
  dwell_minutes INT,
  free_trial_flag CHAR(1),
  unlimited_flag CHAR(1),
  application_version_id VARCHAR(128),
  device_guid CHAR(37),
  device_info_id VARCHAR(128),
  device_brand VARCHAR(128),
  device_product VARCHAR(128),
  device_type VARCHAR(128),
  device_hardware VARCHAR(128),
  device_manufacturer VARCHAR(128),
  device_model VARCHAR(128),
  device_os VARCHAR(128),
  device_os_version VARCHAR(128),
  device_display_info VARCHAR(128),
  device_display_size VARCHAR(128),
  device_display_orientation_id INT,
  event_version INT,
  source_create_timestamp DATETIME,
  source_last_modified_timestamp DATETIME,
  workflow_run_id INT,
  etl_create_date DATETIME,
  etl_update_date DATETIME,
  source_file_id INT
);
```

Now to be able to control values that you insert you can leverage session variables and `SET` clause  of `LOAD DATA INFILE`. E.g. to set absent values to `NULL` in your table you can do

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.txt'
INTO TABLE import_table
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or '\r\n' if the file has been created on a Windows machine
IGNORE 1 LINES -- skip the header line
(
  @nim_event_id,
  @nim_event_data_type_id,
  @nim_event_type_id,
  @event_timestamp,
  @event_gmt_timestamp,
  @product_issue_id,
  @nim_title_id,
  @nim_issue_id,
  @nim_user_id,
  @record_id,
  @transaction_id,
  @dwell_minutes,
  @free_trial_flag,
  @unlimited_flag,
  @application_version_id,
  @device_guid,
  @device_info_id,
  @device_brand,
  @device_product,
  @device_type,
  @device_hardware,
  @device_manufacturer,
  @device_model,
  @device_os,
  @device_os_version,
  @device_display_info,
  @device_display_size,
  @device_display_orientation_id,
  @event_version,
  @source_create_timestamp,
  @source_last_modified_timestamp,
  @workflow_run_id,
  @etl_create_date,
  @etl_update_date,
  @source_file_id
)
SET 
  nim_event_id = NULLIF(@nim_event_id, ''),
  nim_event_data_type_id = NULLIF(@nim_event_data_type_id, ''),
  nim_event_type_id = NULLIF(@nim_event_type_id, ''),
  event_timestamp = NULLIF(@event_timestamp, ''),
  event_gmt_timestamp = NULLIF(@event_gmt_timestamp, ''),
  product_issue_id = NULLIF(@product_issue_id, ''),
  nim_title_id = NULLIF(@nim_title_id, ''),
  nim_issue_id = NULLIF(@nim_issue_id, ''),
  nim_user_id = NULLIF(@nim_user_id, ''),
  record_id = NULLIF(@record_id, ''),
  transaction_id = NULLIF(@transaction_id, ''),
  dwell_minutes = NULLIF(@dwell_minutes, ''),
  free_trial_flag = NULLIF(@free_trial_flag, ''),
  unlimited_flag = NULLIF(@unlimited_flag, ''),
  application_version_id = NULLIF(@application_version_id, ''),
  device_guid = NULLIF(@device_guid, ''),
  device_info_id = NULLIF(@device_info_id, ''),
  device_brand = NULLIF(@device_brand, ''),
  device_product = NULLIF(@device_product, ''),
  device_type = NULLIF(@device_type, ''),
  device_hardware = NULLIF(@device_hardware, ''),
  device_manufacturer = NULLIF(@device_manufacturer, ''),
  device_model = NULLIF(@device_model, ''),
  device_os = NULLIF(@device_os, ''),
  device_os_version = NULLIF(@device_os_version, ''),
  device_display_info = NULLIF(@device_display_info, ''),
  device_display_size = NULLIF(@device_display_size, ''),
  device_display_orientation_id = NULLIF(@device_display_orientation_id, ''),
  event_version = NULLIF(@event_version, ''),
  source_create_timestamp = NULLIF(@source_create_timestamp, ''),
  source_last_modified_timestamp = NULLIF(@source_last_modified_timestamp, ''),
  workflow_run_id = NULLIF(@workflow_run_id, ''),
  etl_create_date = NULLIF(@etl_create_date, ''),
  etl_update_date = NULLIF(@etl_update_date, ''),
  source_file_id = NULLIF(@source_file_id, '')
;
```

You can further tweak it as needed. The above-mentioned statement successfully loaded two sample rows that you've posted

Here is outcome:

```
+--------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| nim_event_id | nim_event_data_type_id | nim_event_type_id | event_timestamp     | event_gmt_timestamp | product_issue_id | nim_title_id | nim_issue_id | nim_user_id | record_id | transaction_id | dwell_minutes | free_trial_flag | unlimited_flag | application_version_id | device_guid                          | device_info_id | device_brand | device_product | device_type | device_hardware | device_manufacturer | device_model | device_os | device_os_version | device_display_info | device_display_size                                                  | device_display_orientation_id | event_version | source_create_timestamp | source_last_modified_timestamp | workflow_run_id | etl_create_date     | etl_update_date     | source_file_id |
+--------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|    103008184 |                    879 |               883 | 2013-12-07 00:30:35 | 2013-12-07 05:30:35 |               -1 |      4800010 |     36000003 |    57700008 |  61906389 |       21385144 |             0 | Y               | Y              | NULL                   | 4c22c4a3-094a-476f-9a48-c67b15c2d3f7 | -2             | NULL         | NULL           | NULL        | NULL            | NULL                | NULL         | NULL      | NULL              | NULL                | NULL                                                                 |                           887 |             2 | 2013-12-06 21:35:39     | 2013-12-06 21:35:39            |            NULL | 2013-12-07 03:31:34 | 2013-12-07 03:31:34 |           NULL |
|     98500241 |                    875 |               880 | 2013-12-07 15:43:37 | 2013-12-07 20:43:37 |               -1 |           -2 |           -2 |    82700012 |  63226292 |           NULL |          NULL | N               | N              | -i6.1.3-APPLE-3.10.0   | 45F4BCE1-A6DC-4A66-A071-7D628FC7522E | 21             | Apple        | iPhone OS      | iPad        | iPad            | Apple               | iPad         | iOS       | 6.1.3             | iPad                | DisplayMetrics{width=768.000000, height=1024.000000, scale=2.000000} |                           887 |             2 | 2013-12-07 12:45:50     | 2013-12-07 12:45:50            |            NULL | 2013-12-07 19:31:34 | 2013-12-07 19:31:34 |           NULL |
+--------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to go about this, here is one way. Some of these steps can be shortened by utilities - I am assuming you have none of them.

Write a program to read the file, and print the length of each field of each row to a separate file. So, you will have files like `field00.txt`, `field01.txt`, etc.
(Note: You can do this using any text editor and `RegEx` easily)
The contents of each file will look like:

```
14
12
15
```

Now you need to find the maximum number in each file. Either write a program or use a text editor to sort the file.

(Note: if you are good with the shell, you can use cut/sort to do all of the above!)

At this point, you will know the maximum length of each field in the table. By using preview, you will be able to infer the data types also. Based on this information, create a description for the table. Try to import the data. If it fails, see the error message and adjust the data types. Try again, until you succeed.

**Edit: Just read your comment.** So here is something, using the terminal:

**Terminal Commands**

(Warning: I do not have acess to a Mac right now and so have not tested this)

First, write each column into its own file:

```
cut -d'|' -f1 bigfile.txt > col01.txt
cut -d'|' -f2 bigfile.txt > col02.txt
cut -d'|' -f3 bigfile.txt > col03.txt
...
cut -d'|' -f20 bigfile.txt > col20.txt
```

Then find the maximum length of each column:

```
awk '{ if (length > max) max = length } END { print max } ' col01.txt
awk '{ if (length > max) max = length } END { print max } ' col02.txt
awk '{ if (length > max) max = length } END { print max } ' col03.txt
...
awk '{ if (length > max) max = length } END { print max } ' col20.txt
```

(Note: Since you are using Mac OS X, `wc -L` will not work.)

Examine the first few values of each column like so:

```
head col01.txt
head col02.txt
...
head col20.txt
```

Now you know the data type and maximum length of each column. Based on this, declare/create your table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @crnlx. I was hoping for something more straight forwards for a non programmer type. I'm sure this method is simple to most folk on this forum but being a little less experienced with MySQL I was hoping to find a quicker, more user friendly way.
I tried loading into PHPmyAdmin too but the file was too large - it simply would not load.

Comment: @DougFirr: Just added some commands for you. Can you try them out?